# How to store a permanent value using javascript to create a trial application

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, persistent-storage

i want to create a trial webpage with static languages that expires after 10 days from running in client computer and if the deadline has been reached it stores a value in client computer that can be used for the notification of deadline and doing some restrictions in application.
 if i do this with cookies when the user resets the browser this value doesnt do its work.

is there any other option for me to store a permanent value??

i shoud note that i dont want to use activex object and i will encrypt the code with software for prevention of viewing the source code... .

thnk

Comment: So you want to put data on a user's computer that he cannot delete? If that were possible and a thousand sites did that, the user would not be amused about all the occupied disk space.

Comment: thnx for the comment DCoder, this is an offline application, and i've chose web technologies to make it possible to put its CONTENT in web, im trying to store a short string or boolean data only when my application runs in offline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the local storage, which is more persistant than cookies, but they are not permanent, also local storage works only with webkit supported browsers like chrome, safari, etc...